# Split rmarkdown presentation code over multiple text files

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have long presentations which I'd like to split between multiple text files. The collection of text files would, ideally, then be passed to `rmarkdown::render` in a single step.  Is this possible?

`rmarkdown::render` checks the `input` argument and warns that only the first element will be used ... so the following will not work:

```
R> rmarkdown::render(c("file1.Rmd", "file2.Rmd"))
```

It occurred to me that I might use a text processing language to join the files before passing them to `rmarkdown`. However, if there's a way to do this from inside `R` that'd be much more convenient.

Is this possible?